# JQuery.jsonParse not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My code is:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
CKEDITOR.instances.post_editor.setData(json.content);
$("#postTitle").val(json.title);
$("#tagInput").val(json.tags);
```

But it doesn't set the values. When I run `console.log(json)` it logs:

> {"title":"Id ,1","content":"
>
> For testing.</s></u></em></strong></p>\r\n","tags":"tags,hu","date":"May 10, 2014, 7:20 pm","id":"1"}

But when I run `console.log(json.title)` it logs: `undefined`

Comment: And what happens when you run `console.log(typeof json)`

Comment: @adeneo It logs: `string`

Comment: @adeneo Why doesn't it return an object like it has to.

Comment: json is not valid with the line break copy and validate json in http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @prashanth Strange, I tested it on my end and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// replace with your first line. Error is \r\n breaking the data string

data = data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
var json = $.parseJSON(data); // OR  "JSON.parse(data);"
```

Answer (score 1):

You must replace `\n`  in value of `content` field before parsing :

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/rD3Jy/1

```
   aa=aa.replaceAll("\n","###")
```

Then ,you can return to the real value after parsing(`JSON.parse`):

```
aa.content.replaceAll("###","\n") ;
```